# "Missing" assets from large S3 asset source

Tags: assets, s3

We have an S3 asset source with ~33k images. In the admin, quite a few aren’t completely loaded (see image below). Users are able to add these to entries but they don’t display on the front end. Sometimes, a few hours later, they will start displaying. These images are accessible and not corrupt on S3 itself.

[image: "Broken" images in assets within Craft CP]

I’m wondering if there’s something specific causing this: PHP memory limits? Some kind of config setting? Server specs? I’ve updated the asset indexes and the task appears to complete with no errors in the log, but there's no change in the asset experience in the admin.

Note that you're able to view and download the asset just fine from within the admin. Just no thumbnail and no display when added to an entry.

Our client is just noticing this issue now that they're adding backdated content, but I suspect that it has existed since we set up this asset source.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I've discovered (thanks to Andris via Craft support) that if I re-upload these "ghost assets", their attributes are correctly populated, so I've been doing that, albeit slowly as they're not sequential. I also noticed that these assets are missing width, height, and size in the `craft_assetfiles` table.

Comment: ~33k images is quite a few. Sounds like Craft started rendering the thumbnails but didn't finish. If you open up the console on your browser (usually something like `cmd + opt + i`) do you see any errors when you browse the assets around the non-generated thumbnail areas? Like scrolling through to that area?

Comment: @cavellblood — nope! These assets don't have thumbnails so the placeholder image loads instead. They're also missing width, height, and size in the `craft_assetfiles` table in the DB, so they're effectively ghosts.